# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getParam' of undefined. for react native unit test using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write unit test cases for react native for very first time..I am getting following error

[image]

AlbumDetailView.js

```js
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Provider, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../style/AlbumDetailView.component.style';


export default class DetailView extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Album Details',
    };

    render() {
      { /* Using the navigation prop we can get the value passed from the previous screen */ }
      const { navigation } = this.props;
      const albumTitle = navigation.getParam('albumTitle', 'Default data');
      const albumImg = navigation.getParam('albumImg', 'some default value');
      const goBackToHome = () => this.props.navigation.goBack(this.props.navigation.state.key);


      return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Provider>
              <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <View style={styles.albumViewContainer}>
                    <Image source = {{ uri: albumImg }} style={styles.imageView} />
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{albumTitle}</Text>
                    <Button mode="contained"
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', { goBackToHome, })}
                        style={styles.buttonStyle} testID='HomeButton'>
                        HOME
                    </Button>
                </View>
              </View>
            </Provider>
          </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
}
```

and I am writing test cases for same as bellow

```js
import 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import AlbumDetailsView from '../component/AlbumDetailsView';


describe('Album Details Screen', () => {

  it('should render Album Details component', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<AlbumDetailsView />);
  });

  it('should render initial layout', () => {
  // when
  const component = shallow(<AlbumDetailsView />);
  // then
  expect(component.getElements()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('should check if BackButton exists', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<AlbumDetailsView />);
    wrapper.findWhere(n => n.name() === 'Button' && n.prop('testID') === 'HomeButton')

  });

});
```

May I know how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mock the `navigation` prop in your test. Of course `getParam` is undefined, since you haven't passed it in your test. It is passed automatically by `react-navigation` when running your app, but inside your tests, you have to manually mock it.

```
it('should render Album Details component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <AlbumDetailsView navigation={{ getParam: jest.fn() }} />
    );
});
```

Now `getParam` won't be `undefined` anymore. Of course, using the above code, won't return anything when calling `getParam('albumTitle')` since in your test `getParam()` is just a `jest.fn()`, which can translate to an empty function that does nothing.

If you want to make it return values, you will have to manually implement the mocked function as well, like

```
it('should render Album Details component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <AlbumDetailsView navigation={{ getParam: (param) => {
            if (param === 'albumTitle') return 'albumTitle';
            ...
        } }} />
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrei.  Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

they recently change the way to pass props
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/upgrading-from-4.x.html#no-more-getparam

Comment: Thanks. But how to handle this while writing unit test cases? will be helpful if you give some example